# SQL display date on fixed frequency

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a query which displays dates in a specific interval.For example if I have an hire_date and the min(hire_date) is 2009-01-01 and the max(hire_date) is 2009-03-1, then the table should display hire_date in frequency of 2 days apart. Like:

```
+---------+
hire_date 
+---------+
2009-01-01
2009-01-03
2009-01-05
2009-01-07
..........
```

The table named Employee_Service contains:

```
ID Number
Hire_date Timestamp
Name Varchar
```

The current query that I use is:

```
select trunc(hire_date) "Date", 
       count(id) "Num Empl Opened"
from Employee_Service 
group by trunc(hire_date) 
order by trunc(hire_date)
```

Is there any way to build a query for this.

Comment: Do you mean something like loop?

Comment: yes, a loop which starts at the earlier date in the table and ends when it matches the latest date. And this is first column, in the second column I would like to display the name of the employee where hire_date matches

Comment: How about data in `hire_date` column?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select trunc(hire_date) "Date",
       count(id) "Num Empl Opened"
from Employee_Service 
where mod(to_char(hire_date,'dd'),2)<>0
and trunc(hire_date) between to_date('2009-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2009-03-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
group by trunc(hire_date)
order by trunc(hire_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DAYS AS
(SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2009-03-01','YYYY-mm-dd')) - ROWNUM*2 D
 FROM ALL_OBJECTS
 WHERE ROWNUM < 365)
SELECT
  DAYS.D
FROM
  DAYS WHERE D >= TO_DATE('2009-01-01','YYYY-mm-dd');
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/31683)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but min and max date are not fixed, they can change. on the other side I cannot use max(hire_date) in where..

Comment: You should post your table and data :) Then we can help

Comment: thanks, I just edited my question including the table and the current query

Answer (score 0):

I guess this query like this would help you

```
select to_date('01/05/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') + level -1 HIRE_DATE
from dual
WHERE MOD(LEVEL,2) <> 0
connect by level <= to_date('01/06/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date('01/05/2014','DD/MM/YYYY') +1;
```

WHERE '01/05/2014' is taken as from date and '01/06/2014' is taken as to date.

So your query would be:

1. IF hire_date is a VARCHAR in DD/MM/YYYY format

   `select to_date(min(hire_date),'DD/MM/YYYY') + level -1 HIRE_DATE
   from dual
   WHERE MOD(LEVEL,2) <> 0
   connect by level <= to_date(max(hire_date),'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date(min(hire_date),'DD/MM/YYYY') +1;`

Or,

1. IF HIRE_DATE IS A DATE FIELD,

   `select (min(hire_date)) + level -1 HIRE_DATE
   from dual
   WHERE MOD(LEVEL,2) <> 0
   connect by level <= (max(hire_date)) - (min(hire_date)) +1;`

**EDIT:**
Max and Min cannot be used with Group by. So use below format:

```
with cte as
(
    select max(hire_date) max_date, min(hire_date) min_date from my_table
    where --- all conditions here
    and rownum=1
)
select (min_date + level -1) hire_dates
from dual
WHERE MOD(LEVEL,2) <> 0
connect by level <= ( max_date - min_date +1 );
```

---

```
with cte as
(
    select max(hire_date) max_date, min(hire_date) min_date from Employee_Service 
)
select (min_date + level -1) "Date", count(id) "Num Empl Opened"
from Employee_Service , cte
WHERE MOD(LEVEL,2) <> 0
group by (min_date + level -1)
connect by level <= ( max_date - min_date +1 )
ORDER BY (min_date + level -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I get an "group function is not allowed here" at the connect by level <= (max(hire_date)) - (min(hire_date)) +1;

Comment: Yup! I missed that. May be you can use a cte for max and min.

Comment: Have edited the answer. Please check if this would help!

Comment: By Executing your query I get the "invalid identifier". I tried to change it as: connect by level <= ( cte.max_date - cte.min_date +1 ) but I still get the same exeption

Comment: @Lindsey: Include CTE in the from clause ` from Employee_Service , cte`

Comment: Oh,sorry, I didn't read carefully. But now I get:"The data types of the operands are not valid for datetime/interval
 arithmetic".... at connect by level...